# I uploaded a tree to Ancestry and it has old UID facts. How do I delete them?

Tags: ancestry.com, gedcom

I uploaded a tree to Ancestry from a gedcom I had created some years ago.  It included some UID facts.  How do I delete these from a personal member tree?

Answer (score 3):

According to a discussion ["UID?"](http://boards.ancestry.com/thread.aspx?mv=flat&m=1126&p=topics.ancestry.membertree.membertrees) on Ancestry.com, UID information was likely written by RootsMagic. It appears to be an extension to the GEDCOM format that is not yet fully supported by all sites/programs. RootsMagic uses it as a (globally) unique identifier for each person in a tree. Ancestry.com clearly can't import this UID record as intended, and so does the best it can by incorporating it as a "fact".

In that thread, the only suggestion is to edit the GEDCOM file, using find/replace to eliminate the UID entries, then re-import the file. Are you able to simply delete your imported tree, then rebuild from the "corrected" GEDCOM? If so, that's probably your best bet. If you merged the import into another tree, I'm afraid I'm not sure what else you can try. That thread suggests that deletion from the member tree is simply not possible.

Comment: But this is not ideal. I don't want to export and re-create my tree due to loss of media. Not worth it.

My tree started out as My Heritage and was exported from Family Tree Builder into Ancestry.

By now they should have provided a mechanism for purging UID fact type entries.

Answer (score 3):

A Gedcom file is just plain text so any good text editor can edit it. Notepad++ which is free and also has a gedcom plugin is an excellent choice. It can do the search and delete your UID facts but ensure that you take all the entries for each UID out of the gedcom there may be more than 1 line to remove per UID.

If you want to post a portion of the gedcom here that shows a complete UID fact then I or someone else here can advise what actually needs to be removed from your file.